# passing { queue: false } to jQuery show()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ui-thread

In the following code, `showLoader` is the first call, but still `loader` doesn't appear, and the reason is `heavyLifting` is blocking the UI thread.

```js
function onClick() {
  showLoader();
  console.log(heavyLifting());
  hideLoader();
}
function showLoader() {
  $('#loader').show();
}
function hideLoader() {
  $('#loader').hide();
}

function heavyLifting() {
  var num = 0;
  console.log('started heavyLifting');
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) { 
    num += Math.random(); 
  }
  console.log('finished heavyLifting');
  return num;
}
```

```css
.hourglass-background {
    position: fixed;
    background: rgba(250,250,250,0.8);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
}
.hourglass {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 48%;
    transform: translate(50%, -50%);
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader" style="display: none">
    <span class="hourglass-background"></span>
    <span class="hourglass">&#8987</span>
</div>
<div>
  <button onclick="onClick()">click me</button>
</div>
```

I want `loader` to appear immidiately, and thought that passing `{ queue: false }` would help, as the [docs say](http://api.jquery.com/show/#show-options):

> If false, the animation will begin immediately

but it doesn't work:

```
$('#loader').show({ queue: false }); // loader still won't appear immidiately
```

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect execution is happening too fast and it's simply not visible long enough. If you add a delay, you can see it's working.

```js
function showLoader() {
  console.log("Show");
  $('#loader').show();
}

function hideLoader() {
  console.log("Hide");
  $('#loader').hide();
}

function heavyLifting() {
  var num = 0;
  console.log('started heavyLifting');
  for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
    num += Math.random();
  }
  console.log('finished heavyLifting');
  return num;
}

var start = Date.now();

function log(str) {
  var dt = Date.now() - start;
  // Log Number of Milliseconds since start and a String to console
  console.log(dt + ": " + str);
}

$(function() {
  log("Page Loaded");
  $(".start.btn").click(function() {
    log("Start Click Event");
    log("Show Loader");
    showLoader();
    log("Start Heavy Lift");
    var lift = heavyLifting();
    log("End Heavy Lift");
    setTimeout(function() {
      log("Hide Loader");
      hideLoader()
    }, 1000);
    console.log(lift);
    log("End Click Event");
  });
});
```

```css
.hourglass-background {
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.8);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
}

.hourglass {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 48%;
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader" style="display: none;">
  <span class="hourglass-background"></span>
  <span class="hourglass">&#8987</span>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="btn start">click me</button>
</div>
```

**Update**

> **queue** (default: true)
>
> A Boolean indicating whether to place the animation in the effects queue. If false, the animation will begin immediately. As of jQuery 1.7, the queue option can also accept a string, in which case the animation is added to the queue represented by that string. When a custom queue name is used the animation does not automatically start; you must call `.dequeue("queuename")` to start it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Twisty. Using a timeout helps, but I'm trying to figure out why does the parameter passed to `show` seems to not do what it's supposed to. I don't think it's the execution that's fast; if you'd add a zero to the for-loop condition, you'll see it takes a considerable time to run, but still `loader` won't show (you can also comment-out the `hide` call to see `loader` appears only after the loop finishes).

Comment: Updated my answer. It looks like `heavyLifting()` takes  5 milliseconds or 1/200th of a second to execute. Even with rendering that would be less than half a second and not enough time for the human eye to catch it. Most video is about 32 FPS. You're basically trying to show a single frame at 200 FPS. So even if you you remove it from animation queue, it's not appearing long enough to see.

Comment: We can make `heavyLifting` work for a longer time (e.g., add a zero: `i < 1000000000`, and it'd average on 16 seconds. BTW, you can use `console.time` and `console.endTime`) and still `loader` won't show. I still can't understand why.